# Error 400 when deleting strikethrough text

Tags: excel, vba

I have Excel VBA code to delete strikethrough text:

```vb
Private Sub DelStrikethroughText()
    'Deletes strikethrough text in all selected cells
    Dim Cell        As Range
    For Each Cell In Selection
        DelStrikethroughs Cell
    Next Cell
End Sub

Private Sub DelStrikethroughs(Cell As Range)
    'deletes all strikethrough text in the Cell
    Dim NewText     As String
    Dim iCh         As Integer
    For iCh = 1 To Len(Cell)
        With Cell.Characters(iCh, 1)
            If .Font.Strikethrough = False Then
                NewText = NewText & .Text
            End If
        End With
    Next iCh
    Cell.Value = NewText
    Cell.Characters.Font.Strikethrough = False
End Sub
```

The code works on some cells.

The code fails at the last cell of the first row (so it depends on my selection). The macro is interrupted, just as it is supposed to change to row 2.

The cursor stops at `NewText = NewText & .Text`.

Why does Excel throw error 400?

Comment: Have you looked up error 400? Have you stepped through your code to see where the problem lies?

Comment: `Len(Cell)?` Shouldn't that be `Len(Cell.Value)`?

Comment: @SJR When I step through, the code runs just fine. And as far as I know, error 400 is just a generic "something wrent wrong" kind of error
It only shows an error, when it processes approx. >10 cells

Comment: @Dominique Unfortunately, changing it to `Len(Cell.Value)` did not fix the problem for me

Comment: At which line do you get the error? What value has the cell that throws the error?

Comment: Did some tests and it run OK with random selection of cells in multiple columns and rows, even empty and non formatted ones. Cannot reproduce the Error :(

Comment: I'm getting an error where there is a formula. Maybe ignore any cells that contains a formula would do the trick

Comment: @Ike Unfortunately I do not know, where exactly the problem occurs, because I do not get the error message when debugging

Comment: @TomNavidi My Excel file does not contain formulas, but thanks for the advice

Comment: if you open the immediate window during debug and type `print cell.address` you can check which cell causes the problem, you may find the reason there. Another question; are there any merged cells in your excel file?

Comment: @TomNavidi Thanks for the hint. The immediate window shows: My code always fails at the last cell of the first row (so it depends on my selection). So the macro is interrupted, just as it is supposed to change to row 2.
The cursor stops at this line `NewText = NewText & .Text`

But why is there a problem?

Comment: try copy the cells and the code to a new file, then run from there.......... cannot replicate the problem at my end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cell.Characters.Text does not work for cells containing formulas, numbers, dates etc. you can use Mid() function instead, however this may convert existing numbers to text:

```
Private Sub DelStrikethroughText()
    'Deletes strikethrough text in all selected cells
    Dim Cell        As Range
    For Each Cell In Selection
        If Cell.NumberFormat = "General" Then DelStrikethroughs Cell
    Next Cell
End Sub

Private Sub DelStrikethroughs(Cell As Range)
    'deletes all strikethrough text in the Cell
    Dim NewText     As String
    Dim iCh         As Integer
    For iCh = 1 To Len(Cell)
        With Cell.Characters(iCh, 1)
            If .Font.Strikethrough = False Then
                NewText = NewText & Mid(Cell, iCh, 1)
            End If
        End With
    Next iCh
    Cell.Value = NewText
    Cell.Characters.Font.Strikethrough = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code snippet does not delete Strikethrough text in my case, so the issue could be: Cell.HasRichDataType?

Comment: I've done some changes now, time formats were converted to number stored as text, so i added the `If Cell.NumberFormat = "General"` statement, also changed .Text of .Characters(iCh, 1) to `Mid(Cell, iCh, 1)` to avoid the number-not-text-error. It seems to be working now

Comment: Thank you so much, adding Mid seems to work just fine for me! Thanks again